# form action to display a hidden div and then go to the .php page in the form action?

Tags: php, jquery

This is a bit difficult to explain but I will try my best.

I have a `<form>` that has an action. in the form action I have a `.php` file that executes a few PHP functions once the form is submit. this works fine.

I also have a div with a `display:none;` in the page with the form.

now, what I want to do is to display the DIV that is hidden for a few seconds once the form is submitted and then go to the form action which is the `.php page` so it can execute the PHP functions.

I did try the following code however, it will display the hidden div and will not execute the PHP page nor dose it go to the .php page in the form action!

I thought about using AJAX but AJAX executes the PHP code/page behind the scene so it won't direct the users to the `.php` page in the form action. I need the users to go to the `.php` page so using AJAX is out of question.

**Here is the code for form:**

```
<form action="execute.php" method="post" name="orderform" class="register">
  <input name="firstname" type="text" class="long" id="firstname"  />
  <input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname"  />
</form>
```

**and here is the code to display the hidden div:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#submit").click(function(){
     $( "#div" ).show('slow');
   });
</script>
```

could someone please help me out with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you think that ajax wouldn't submit the data? Put an ajax call just below the click function, and put the ".show" in a .done statement.

Comment: You can't update the HTML of a page once you've submitted a form (not via ajax). You have to wait for the next page to load. What you probably want to do is catch the form submission action, show the div, then submit the form. I can provide code if it sounds like what you need.

Comment: using Ajax is not out of the question, this is common and can be done using ajax. On the success event of the ajax callback you can redirect your user to the .php file. If you don't want to use Ajax, then you can use JavaScript to post the form, before calling. On submit event, show div then $form).submit(), the div will show for as long as it takes the form to post. If you want to wait longer, use setInterval with a duration then call $(form).submit();

Comment: @TimSPQR, I never said AJAX doesn't send the data. I said it will send the data behind the scene which is not what I am looking for. I need the users to go the PHP page once the form is submitted.

Comment: ok, you dont need ajax actually. what you desire is what @René Roth posted as answer. what you think how it should be done is wrong. bcoz you want to redirect to same form which you wish to be submited and after show hidden field and then get redirected to the php is not good structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
     $( "#div" ).show('slow');
     setTimeout(function(){$('form[name=orderform]').submit();},5000);
     e.preventDefault();
   });
```

Comment: Did you try my solution? the `.submit()` function is supposed to execute the form action.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `complete` callback that is part of the [show](https://api.jquery.com/show/) function

```
<form action="execute.php" method="post" name="orderform" class="register" id="myform">
  <input name="firstname" type="text" class="long" id="firstname"  />
  <input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname"  />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#submit").click(function(){
     $( "#div" ).show('slow', function(){$("#myform").submit()});
   });
</script>
```

Comment: If the submit button is an actual submit input button, you'll need to prevent the default action.

Comment: @Relequestual Given the OP's comment of "it will display the hidden div and will not execute the PHP page nor dose it go to the .php page in the form action", I took the liberty of assuming that the click alone was not triggering the submit.

Comment: Totally fair comment. Missed that.

Comment: I did try this one as well and nothing happens. it will display the hidden div as it was before but i will not go to the php page and it will not execute it either! my submit button is this: `<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">`

Answer (score 0):

You could call an ajax function and when it "finishes the work" you redirect the user like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#submit").click(function(){
     $( "#div" ).show('slow');
       $.ajax("page.php", { 
          data: $('form[name=orderform]').serialize()
       }).done(function(returnedData){
          location.href = 'theUrlYouWant.php?stuff=' + returnedData;
       });
   });
</script>
```

Hope it helps